# Cannot use invoke for specific Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a method that disable the whole UserControl. But if i a disable the whole Layout it seems very bad(disabled grids, labes looks so gray). So i decided catch controls in layout and disable them manually. but invoke method only if i disable the layout not for controls. How can this method in UserControls ?

```
   public static void Enable(this Control con, bool isEnable)
            {
                if (con != null)
                {
                        foreach (Control ctrl in con.Controls)
                        {    
                            var a = ctrl.GetType().Name;
                            var b = ctrl.Name;

                            if (ctrl is TfSearchButton)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfNumericEdit)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfCheckEdit)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfComboEdit)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                //ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfTextEdit)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfRadioGroup)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfDateEdit)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfLookUpEdit)
                            {
                                ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl is TfGrid)
                            {
                                GridView view = ((TfGrid)ctrl).MainView as GridView;
                                view.OptionsBehavior.Editable = isEnable;
                                ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => view.OptionsBehavior.Editable = isEnable));
                            }
                            if (ctrl.GetType().BaseType.Name is "TfControlBase" || ctrl is TfLayoutControl)
                            {
                                Enable(ctrl, isEnable);
                            }

                        }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just for the record: It's WinForms?

Comment: I can see a problematic pattern in your code, but just to be sure, what is the observed misbehavior?

Comment: basically i cannot make my textbox radiobutton or checkboxes enabled = false with my method. but i can disable my whole layout

Comment: You mean, no change occurs to the enabled state, no exception is thrown, and the application continues to work?

Comment: yes the code i write in invoke method is only works with layout not the controls in layouts.  dunno why i cant disable controls in layout. the point is  layouts has layouts in it so i have to make specific controls's enabled false

Comment: And why do you use Invoke, is Enable() running on a different thread?

Comment: yes it runs on a different thread and the method will be a common method for disable controls for forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I find is that you access controls both without Invoke and with Invoke:

```cs
ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
ctrl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ctrl.Enabled = isEnable));
```

Since `Invoke` is required because we must access control handle only from the thread that created it, and if we're not sure whether we're running on that thread, we must use `InvokeRequired` and if it returns `true`, we must use `Invoke`.

To cover both cases, we can factor the code like this:

```cs
private static void InvokeControl(Control ctrl, Action<Control> action)
{
    if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ctrl.Invoke(() => action(ctrl));
    }
    else
    {
        action(ctrl);
    }
}

public static void Enable(this Control con, bool isEnable)
{
    if (con == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (Control ctrl in con.Controls)
    {    
        if (ctrl is TfSearchButton)
        {
            InvokeControl(ctrl, c => c.Enabled = isEnable);
        }
        //... implement the rest of the cases in similar way
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

Giving it some more thought, switching enabled state of multiple controls in this case is, logically, an atomic operation. In solution I suggested above, one call to `Enable()` would result in numerous context switches and thread blocking. To make the `Enable()` operation "a more atomic" technically, it's better to run `Enable()` entirely on the UI thread:

```cs
public static void Enable(this Control con, bool isEnable)
{
    if (con == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (con.InvokeRequired) // returns false if we're on the UI thread
    {
        // if we're not on the UI thread, enqueue a new call to Enable()
        // the call will be dequeued and executed by the UI thread
        con.BeginInvoke(() => Enable(con, isEnable));
        return; 
    }

    // if we got to this point, we're running on the UI thread

    foreach (Control ctrl in con.Controls)
    {    
        // since this code always runs on UI thread,
        // there is no need to use Invoke/BeginInvoke

        if (ctrl is TfSearchButton)
        {
            ctrl.Enabled = isEnable;
        }
        // ... the rest of the cases ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for realising that invoke actions for multiple times. But your code only work if i use begininvoke instead of invoke. what is the point on that. is it safe to change your code with begininvoke ?

Comment: The main difference is that Invoke() uses SendMessage() API, which blocks until the message is handled by the UI thread. Whereas BeginInvoke() uses PostMessage() API, which returns immediately. If you observe deadlocks when using Control.Invoke(), it possibly indicates that your Enable() method (or any other code that calls Invoke()) runs concurrently on multiple threads. In such a case, switching to BeginInvoke() would resolve the deadlock, but it won't necessarily be the correct solution: you'll get a mix of updates sent simultaneously from multiple threads.

Comment: I think it would be better to run Enable() entirely in the UI thread, that is, Invoke(() => Enable(...)) and then you don't need InvokeControl()